# How to find values less than -1 in each row for every 12 columns in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix(100*120) and I am trying to find values <=-1 in each row for every 12 columns. I have tried several times but failed. It is easy to find values which are <= -1, but I do not know how to consider for every 12 columns and store the results for each row. Thanks for any help.

```
set.seed(100)
Mydata <- sample(x=-3:3,size = 100*120,replace = T)
Mydata <- matrix(data = Mydata,nrow = 100,ncol = 120)
results <- which(Mydata<=-1,arr.ind = T)
```

Comment: show us your previous attempts so we can build from there and you can understand what you did wrong...

Comment: Thanks. I just edited the question.

Comment: So what's wrong with your code? Why is it unsatisfactory?

Comment: That is because I do not know how to consider for every 12 columns and store the results for each row, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the apply function to apply the which function across each column for each row at a time. If I misinterpreted what you wanted, you can adjust the MARGIN argument accordingly.

```
# MARGIN=1 to apply across rows
dd <- apply(Mydata,MARGIN=1,function(x) which(x <= -1))
dd[1] # which columns in row 1 have a value <= -1
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I consider for every 12 columns and store the results for each row?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a combination of apply functions and `seq()`

```
#Example Data
set.seed(100)
Mydata <- sample(x=-3:3,size = 100*120,replace = T)
Mydata <- matrix(data = Mydata,nrow = 100,ncol = 120)

#Solution:
Myseq <- sapply(0:9,function(x) seq(1,12,1) + 12*x)
sapply(1:dim(Myseq)[2], function(x) which(Mydata[,Myseq[,x]] == -1))
```

This results in a list with:

- each subset of the list representing one of your 10 groups of 12 columns
- each value under each subset representing the position in the matrix of any value in those 12 columns with a value equal to -1.